# Overrode Lead Conversion: OOB lead with converted information report shows no Opportunity data

Tags: reporting

in our organization ,we have overwritten the convert functionality of lead into opportunity to attain certain business process.now when i go to standard report types for lead and select "LEad with converted lead information",i get the lead information but not the opportunity information.does overriding the convert break this ? pls help. thanks

Comment: Are you using Database.convertLead? If so, it should work as you expect.

Comment: we aren't using that cause it creates contacts and account

Comment: If you don't use it, you can't have "leads with converted lead information." And that method does not *necessarily* create contacts and accounts if you provide specific record Ids.

Comment: what is the way i build my reports showing lead with opp info ?in this case

Comment: Unless you have a custom lookup field to track the relationship, you can't get such a report.

Comment: lookup on lead or opp?

Comment: Doesn't really matter-- it's your custom conversion routine. You'll need to modify your code to make sure the lookup field is populated.